# Invoke-Expression: Positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument /s

Tags: powershell, ssh, installation, telnet, silent

I have a .ps1 script which contains a line

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "C:\Builds\$BuildName /s /v`"/l*v c:\build_install.txt /qn`""<br/>
```

This is performing Silent installation of a product.

Now, if I try to run this command from Linux box through ssh it gives the following error:

```
Invoke-Expression : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/s'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Expression C:\NWTBuilds\Setup-NimbleNWT-x64.2.0.4.117.exe /s /v`/l*v c:\n ...
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

Do you have any suggestions on this? Do I need to provide any credentials?

So I have also tried the following options:

1. Send the command through ssh or telnet `powershell.exe -Command ...`
2. Call the powershell Script from ssh or telnet `powershell.exe -File C:\Sample.ps1`

However If I ran the same `Sample.ps1` from windows Powershell, silent installation is done?

Comment: I got this fixed without using powerShell.                                 BuildName is : Windows-NNN-Setup-x64.2.12.3.109.exe

Answer (score 4):

Your **/s** is being interpreted as being part of your **Invoke-Expression** call.  Can you try **Invoke-Command**, i.e.:

```
Invoke-Command { C:\Builds\$BuildName /s /v "/l*v c:\build_install.txt /qn" }
```

Comment: I tried the above command it did not worked. I even tried the following option  Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { "C:\Builds\$BuildName /s /v'`/l*v c:\build_install.txt /qn`""}

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that PowerShell is trying to parse `/s` as the name of a parameter of **Invoke-Expression** rather than as part of the argument supplied to **-Command**, which it would not do if the `/s` were part of the string. This implies that the string is being terminated just before that. Check the value of **$BuildName**, it probably contains something that terminates the string. I'm not quite sure what that might be, because a pair of double quotes within the variable value *shouldn't* have that effect. At least it wouldn't at a PowerShell prompt. Maybe the ssh client is interpreting what you're typing in some way that terminates the string before `/s`?

In any case, I'd be willing to bet money that the answer lies in the value of **$BuildName**, because logically the error indicates that the string argument to **-Command** terminates at that point.

Comment: Thanks Adi, the Build Name is "mcmattu-2.0.0.1.exe". the thing is it is working if I get rid of Powershell altogether and let it run on default cmd prompt.

Comment: Can you show the code that assigns **$BuildName**? There *has* to be something in there that terminates the string (maybe some nonprinting character at the end?), because what the error is telling you is that the string is being terminated at that point, and `/s` is parsed as an argument to **iex**.

Comment: $BuildName = "Windows-NNN-Setup-x64.2.12.3.109.exe"

Comment: I'm confused. You said above that Build Name is "mcmattu-2.0.0.1.exe", but now you're saying that you're assigning "Windows-NNN-Setup-x64.2.12.3.109.exe" to **$BuildName**. Which is it? Also...try `$test = "C:\Builds\$BuildName /s /v\`"/l*v c:\build_install.txt /qn\`""; Write-Host $test` and see what you get back.