# Set-Location: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument _fullpath_

Tags: powershell

I've read several similar posts but they focus on calling a PS script from within another PS script. I can do that and make the other script run, my issue is most likely linked to $MyInvocation when calling a script from another script.

#### Background

I have a script that half-way through needs to call another script. This other script cannot be a psm1 module because it is used as a standalone script in other processes. I begin the script with

```
$ScriptDir = (split-path -parent -path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
```

#### Problem

I then run

```
& "$ScriptDir\Another Script.ps1"
```

This throws the following error

```
Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Scripts'.
At C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Scripts\Another Script.ps1:30 char:1
+ Set-Location = $ScriptDir
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Here's the full section of the Another Script.ps1 that is failing

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$ScriptDir = (split-path -parent -path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
Set-Location = $ScriptDir
```

My guess is that the Set-Location does not work because it is currently running a script inside another script. The problem I have is that this part needs to be there in order for Another Script.ps1 to run as a standalone script as well. Are there any workarounds for this, such as ignoring this step if it's run from another script?

#### References

- https://paulcunningham.dev/powershell-invoke-expressions-spaces-in-path/
- [Invoke-Expression: Positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument /s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666599/invoke-expression-positional-parameter-cannot-be-found-that-accepts-argument-s)
- [Call PowerShell script PS1 from another PS1 script inside Powershell ISE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816450/call-powershell-script-ps1-from-another-ps1-script-inside-powershell-ise)
- [Powershell: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument "xxx"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433151/powershell-a-positional-parameter-cannot-be-found-that-accepts-argument-xxx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't believe I missed it: Set-Location should not have an equal sign.

It currently says

```
Set-Location = $ScriptDir
```

When it should say

```
Set-Location $ScriptDir
```